# Plotting Line Graph Different Worksheets using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 7 Excel Worksheets containing data that I want to use to produce a line graph with markers. I'm able to create the line graph on the first worksheet however I can't recreate the right graph on the second worksheet. I just recorded a macro to get an idea of how to plot in VBA so I'm not sure if this is the best way to produce linegraphs but essentially the first column A will contain the X-values and the other Columns B - I will contain the Y Data Values.

Here is a snip of my code:

```
    Worksheets("OCM_VMonM24").Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("OCM_VMonM24!$A$1:$I$2544")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=OCM_VMonM24!$A$3:$A$2544"

    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "O-CAMS -24V"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "O-CAMS -24V"
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Self_Test_GV"
```

That works for correctly plotting the data on the first worksheet, so I just tried copying and pasting for the other worksheet however it just plots over the graph in the first Excel worksheet with the data from the second worksheet. Here is copy and pasted version:

```
    Worksheets("OCM_VMonM12").Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("OCM_VMonM12!$A$1:$I$2544")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=OCM_VMonM12!$A$3:$A$2544"

    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "O-CAMS -12V"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "O-CAMS -12V"
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Self_Test_GV"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change your code a bit:

```
With Worksheets("OCM_VMonM24").Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Chart
  .SetSourceData Source:=Range("OCM_VMonM24!$A$1:$I$2544")
  .FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
  .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=OCM_VMonM24!$A$3:$A$2544"

  With .ChartTitle
    .Text = "O-CAMS -24V"
    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "O-CAMS -24V"
  End With
  .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Self_Test_GV"
End With
```

also... you may only add

```
 Worksheets("OCM_VMonM12").Activate
```

in front of

```
 Worksheets("OCM_VMonM12").Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
```

selecting a shape in a nonactive sheet leads often to errors...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately I received a Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. The line the error occurs is the:       .SetSourceDataSource:=Range("OCM_VMonM24!$A$1:$I$2544").

Comment: @TheDon sorry for that... i just tried to avoid `select` without testing ^^; but have you tried to simply make the sheet to work with active? does that help?

Comment: @TheDon i changed the main-code... pls try it again